# Framework to build cross-platform app with offline image classifier, map, CSV parsing

Tags: software-development, mobile

I am building an app which is based on catalogue of caterpillar information where the user can look at a catalogue of caterpillars and look up information about them. I need a backend that could:

1. Connect to the Google Maps API
2. A database to store the information about the catarpillars such as (color, description, location and etc) that also needs to be easily modifiable. It will need to be able to parse information from a csv. file.
3. I need to connect the app to an Image Classifier that I made in Python Tensorflow as the app will have a feature where the user will be able to take an image of a caterpillar and the Image Classifier will identify the species of it.
4. It will need to be able to run without the internet.
5. Cross Platform

Sorry I am still new to Backend and still trying to figure it out for my app, sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: Please mention in details what should work when offline. For instance the maps? Is the CSV file hosted on your server or embed within the app?

Comment: What OS should it run on? Android and iOS only is OK?

Comment: Yes it is Android and iOS only. The CSV File is embed within the app. During offline I want the image classifier and Maps feature to be still usable.

Comment: Can it be another map provider than Google Maps?

Comment: Yes it could be another map provider